# WIth Date Condition Doesn't Fire

Tags: designer-workflow

If Current:ReminderDate equals Today

This condition doesn't fire, so is there another way of coding this.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by logging the value of reminderdate to the workflow log to check on the actual value, as well as the value of Today. Dates can certainly be tricky as that dates can include times, which will throw off comparisons. Assuming that remdinderdate is indeed a date field, perhaps try using: if RemdinderDate < Today. The less then could avoid issues if the times don't exactly match.